# Need help adjusting an animation to also be a clickable link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Hey so my experience with html and css is limited.  I can modify code based on what I know but im awful at writing it .  Any way I would appreciate help with this other source of code I'd like to turn this entire code into a link.  how would I do that?

Im not entirely sure where I would add the infor for a link.

Tried adding a:link and href link.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
.word{
 display: flex;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 margin: 5%;
}

.l-anim{
  transform: translateY(50%);
  width: 100%
}

.c-anim{
transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%
}

.ed-anim{
transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-10%) scale(.70);
width: 100%
}

.word:hover .l-anim, .word:hover .c-anim, .word:hover .ed-anim{
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: 1s all;
}

.word:not(:hover) .l-anim{
  transform: translateY(50%);
  transition: 1s all;
}

.word:not(:hover)  .c-anim{
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 1s all;
}

.word:not(:hover) .ed-anim{
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 1s all;
}



</style>
</head>


<div class="word">
  <div>SE</div>
  <div class="anim-wrapper">
    <div class="l-anim">L</div>
  </div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div class="anim-wrapper">
    <div class="c-anim">C</div>
  </div>
  <div>T</div>
  <div class="anim-wrapper">
    <div class="ed-anim">ED</div>
  </div>

</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

If the link need to open a new tab, a `target="_blank"` property can be added to `<a>` tag to achieve it. However in some cases, this could make the link blocked by a browser.

**Original**

This example adds the entire element as a link.

To change the link address, edit `href` value in the `<a>` tag (the first line of HTML).

Hope this will help.

Example: (see live demo with button below)

```css
.word{
 display: flex;
 width: fit-content;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 margin: 5%;
 cursor: pointer;
}

a.word:link, a.word:visited, a.word:hover {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

.l-anim{
  transform: translateY(50%);
  width: 100%
}

.c-anim{
transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%
}

.ed-anim{
transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-10%) scale(.70);
width: 100%
}

.word:hover .l-anim, .word:hover .c-anim, .word:hover .ed-anim{
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: 1s all;
}

.word:not(:hover) .l-anim{
  transform: translateY(50%);
  transition: 1s all;
}

.word:not(:hover)  .c-anim{
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 1s all;
}

.word:not(:hover) .ed-anim{
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 1s all;
}
```

```html
<!-- To open a new tab for link, add target="_blank" to <a> -->
<!-- Change the link url in here  -->
<a class="word" href="https://en.wikipedia.org">


  <div>SE</div>
  <div class="anim-wrapper">
    <div class="l-anim">L</div>
  </div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div class="anim-wrapper">
    <div class="c-anim">C</div>
  </div>
  <div>T</div>
  <div class="anim-wrapper">
    <div class="ed-anim">ED</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: for some reason when i try this, it underlines each letter. why is that?

Comment: also when i click - it doesnt open a new tab - it just opens within the code

Comment: @Joshua It seems that this website does not allow opening new tabs from snippet, but I added some instructions about it. The underline might come from other global settings, I put some strict rules in CSS to force it, but depending on running environment, it might or might not work. Thanks.